# Edit Summary textbox disappears after changing the screen orientation in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, edit-summary

**The setup**

Suggesting an edit to some post on the Android app

**The problem**

If I ever switch from portrait mode to landscape mode (by turning my phone sideways), the *Edit Summary* box disappears.

[image: Before switching to landscape mode]
[image: After switching to landscape mode (and back)]

<sup>Before and after changing screen orientation</sup>

On the left is the normal behavior. The right image shows what happens after I switch to landscape mode and back; notice how the *Edit Summary* box is missing.

This problem is 100% reproducible on my phone.

**The specs**

Nexus 5 running Android 5.1.1, Stack Exchange app version 1.0.68.

Comment: Repro'd on v1.0.69 beta. To be exact, the edit summary box will disappear when changing the screen orientation (as per this post's title). This also occurs when the starting orientation is landscape, then rotate to portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

Orientation changes on Android are weird.